# Is it possible to give an ASP.NET MVC route more server resources than others?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8, high-availability

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC REST web service.
The webservice has two major paths/routes.  One for admin, one for users.
There users are typically 1-2 admin users, and all other users are normal.
When there is a lot of traffic, the server becomes slow to respond. Currently, this means that the admin users requests are slow just like regular users.
I want the admin users requests (which use a particular route) to have top priority such that the admin requests are fast, as if there was no load on the server.  A way to think about this is I want to create VIP access for admins.

One option I thought of would be just to create another server, however there are some dependencies between actions on the admin route and actions on the user route, so there would need to be additional code written to facility inter-server communication, which in turn may create a new bottleneck.

I think this can be done via code, perhaps a custom request queue which could implement priorities by creating a separate worker thread pool and give them high priority however, would this actually work - meaning a thread pool of 5 worker threads given highest priority still have priority over the main ASP.NET worker thread pool which run at default priority?

The ideal solution I am looking for a solution that requires only configuration, a small amount of code, and no new hardware.  Is this possible?

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (iis8).

Regarding existing bottlenecks:
This is mostly a CPU bound issue, I've looked at the performance counters while running load test.  its really just an overloaded server situation, where I want to protect the performance of the admin route, and the users can temporarily suffer until the load lessens (meaning I don't want to invest in adding more capacity)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with prioritize Http requests on IIS server.
As you mentioned, the quickest solution is to use another server. if you use the same code base and the same database, you do not have add even a line of code.

But maybe you should investigate your problem a bit more and find your bottleneck, CPU, Memory, DB, Http requests...

Comment: I updated the post regarding bottlenecks.

Comment: I would agree about no new code if the admin actions and user actions didn't have a real-time interaction between them.  If I run two servers, then the admin actions don't interact with the users on the other server and vise versa out of the box.  The database is not the bridge in my application due to the added latency.

Comment: I understand your point about two servers. Again I don't know any prioritized IIS queue, but even if there is one it wont do you any good. Lets say your admin will pop first from the IIS queue, still their requests will be facing with limited resources shared by all other users. You just can't preserve resources for specific user on a leggy machine.

Comment: I think adding a server is a good way to go, and may be preferable for some designs.  I may be forced into it.  However to your last point, the limited resources, yes, I suppose, but if we focus on CPU resources for now, which is my problem, then I think I can control this at least to some degree using a separate thread pool?  This was a subquestion I posed.  I guess I might have to try it out to see.  Hoping someone already knows. :)

Comment: It's pretty hard core but read this: http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

Comment: I get where your pushing me, however this isn't a "performance" issue.  This is a server overload.  Think like 5k concurrent requests.  I can vertically scale by upping my instance size in the cloud, but then I run into the same problem when we have 10k users, 20k, etc.